# Как использовать ioctl при работе с устройствами в Linux?

Tags: драйвер, linux

Как использовать ioctl при работе с устройствами в Linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Открыть файловый дескриптор.
2. Получить или установить параметры устройства.
3. Закрыть файловый дескриптор

Например, получить значение DSR (Data Set Ready) последовательного порта.

```
int descriptor, status, dsr;

descriptor = open("/dev/ttyS0", O_RDONLY);
ioctl(descriptor, TIOCMGET, &status);
close(descriptor);

dsr = status & TIOCM_DSR ? 1 : 0;
```